# Need help on converting sequence to matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, sequence

Below is the sequence that I need to convert to a MATLAB function sequence.  Specifically, given `{an}` and `n ≥ 0`, such that defined by `a0 = 3`, `a1 = 2`, and `an = 2a(n−1) − 8/9a(n−2)` for `n > 1`

So far, I have:

```
function F = Sequence

if n==0

F = 0;

else

Fn1 = 0; F = 3;

Fn2 = 1; F = 2;

for k = 3:n

Fn3 = Fn2; Fn2 = F;

F = 2Fn1-(8/9)Fn2;

end

end
```

Comment: What do you mean by a "Matlab function sequence"?  What should be the inputs and outputs of your function?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
function [ output_seq ] = get_sequence( seq_length )

output_seq = [3 2];

for iter = 3 : seq_length
    output_seq(end + 1) = 2 * output_seq(end) ...
        - 8 / 9 * output_seq(end - 1);
end
end
```

Comment: would you know how to obtain an explicit function for this sequence